# Unable to Start VMware due to .lck - How To Fix?

Tags: vmware, lock, vmware-player, vmdk

When I try and start VMware, I get this error:

[image]

I found this .lck directory, which contains a M45876.lck file. 
[image]

I am not sure how to safely remove this file, or do I remove the entire directory, or both?

Comment: I would just delete the lock directory but if you're uneasy then just move it out to a temp directory. You can move it back if VB complains but I don't think it will.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenBoston - I was over thinking it.